# Any possible combination in a list?

Tags: python, combinations

I am currently following [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list). The recommended solution implements the ordered solution i.e. if you have A, B then combinations are A, B, AB.

Nevertheless, I would like to include any possible ordering of elements i.e. A, B, BA, AB. Is there any way to do that in Python?

Thank you.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "permutations"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
import itertools

xs = 'a', 'b'
for n in range(1, len(xs)+1):
    for ys in itertools.permutations(xs, n):
        print(ys)
```

prints

```
('a',)
('b',)
('a', 'b')
('b', 'a')
```

Comment: you are amazing:) i will accept the answer as soon as i can (in 9 minutes) since i am new here i cannot accept right away

Comment: @Martin you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left of the post, to upvote you will need 15 reputations.

Comment: thank you :) i clicked it now :) thansks again man